# What happens with the partial wake lock if the process that acquires is killed?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

Does it get released automatically if the process didn't released before it was killed?

Comment: you need to release it in `onDestroy()`

Comment: Yes it do release but not immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wakelock is released if Process is killed. You can check this by below method

Acquire a wakelock and then run

```
  adb shell dumpsys power
```

kill the process from ddms. Again run dumpsys power

You can see that the mlocks.size is back to 0.