# Android - Ensuring that Wakelock is released when a Service's process is killed by OS

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-wake-lock

I want my `FusedLocationProvider` to ping for location even when the screen is off. For this, in my service, I have a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`, to keep the CPU running and to ensure that the service continues to run even when the screen is off.

That being said, I know the Android OS will kill off services/apps in the background when it needs memory. Due to this, my service can be killed off.

When this happens, `onDestroy()` in the `Service` is not guaranteed to be called. If that is the case, how do I ensure that the WakeLock gets released?

I call `mWakeLock.acquire();` in `onStartCommand`, and in `onDestroy` I call `mWakeLock.release();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do I ensure that the WakeLock gets released?

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle):

```
If the service is currently executing code in its onCreate(), 
onStartCommand(), or onDestroy() methods, then the hosting process will be a 
foreground process to ensure this code can execute without being killed.
```

What this means is that if the code in any of those methods is currently being executed, then the process won't be killed (or at least will be given a very high priority) till the code finishes executing.

However, the short answer to your question is that there is **NO** way to *ensure* that `onDestroy()` or `onPause()` gets called. `onPause()`, though, does have a far greater probability of getting called, so you could look into that. There is also a method, [`Application.onTerminate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29) which you may want to use for further research on this. The method is only called when running the app on emulators.

I don't think you need to worry about a memory *leak*, though (assuming that we are both on the same page regarding what such a leak constitutes). When a process is killed, the memory is reclaimed by the kernel, not by the GC, so there isn't going to be a memory leak in that case.

**EDIT:**

I have confirmed that if a process is killed, an acquired wakelock will necessarily be released:

**1.** [**Does the android os release a wakelock if the app or service holding it is killed ?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697873/does-the-android-os-release-a-wakelock-if-the-app-or-service-holding-it-is-kille).

**2.** [**What happens with the partial wake lock if the process that acquires is killed ?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296767/what-happens-with-the-partial-wake-lock-if-the-process-that-acquires-is-killed).

**3.** [**Binders & Death Recipients**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/binders-death-recipients.html).

**4.** [**How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-to-deal-with-orphaned-wakelocks).

Comment: Yeah, I guess memory leak was poor wording. My main worry is that my WakeLock never gets released and my app will be draining battery due to a CPU always being active.